# How thick of a layer of wood chips will I want to keep the soil warm in a USDA zone 4A environment during the winter?

Tags: compost, fungus, mushrooms

I'm currently building a 10X100 fungal/garden bed, in a USDA zone 4A environment, and am going to want to keep the soil warm enough to keep fungi spreading. How deep will I want a layer of wood chips to try to keep the area warm enough, but not so warm that it it's like a sauna into the spring. I can tell you that the creek running about 10-20 feet away only develops a thin layer of ice in the dead of winter due to the natural bacterial environment of bog bacteria.

Comment: Zone 4A?  2 feet and make sure that you add a little pure nitrogen to the piles of chips.  Bog bacteria on a creek?  10 to 20 feet away?  Please tell me that you are looking into the regulations for your creek and development?  Why would ice form because of bacteria? Or is fungus involved?  What is it you imagine that the fungi does that is so beneficial, black thumb?  You work very hard.

Comment: I already talked with the watershed district, and they're interested in having me do some community service with mycoremediation also. I want a mycoremediation zone in my own back yard so I can get fungi to eat constantly (i.e. go out to the garden, and pick a nice tasty mushroom just like you pick a carrot or tomato, but boil it in a coffee cup, or pot before consumption). Late fall I plan to ask for more leafy material to do the winter spreading so it will break down quickly enough in early spring if not by mid winter.

Comment: @stormy we're also zoned as rural, and it's a private ditch that has a gas pipeline running through it, not an actual creek/stream

Comment: Interesting.  So there is no water running down this ditch?  Even intermittent water ways are buffered.  Gas pipeline, huh?  Remember the one that broke in Bellingham, WA?  25 years ago?  The two boys playing with firecrackers?  Ugh.

Comment: Please keep us updated with the community service stuff!

Comment: Mycoremediation is interesting.  Have absolutely no background at all on producing MORE fungi.  I thought is was always here and there and everywhere.

Comment: @stormy we had the road construction crew break the main line a couple years ago, and they wouldn't let me drive home, when I told them my home was right next to the pipeline when they weren't evacuating the houses

Comment: Well, scary?!! Dontchathink?

Answer (score 2):

Lots! What's wrong with a sauna? Fungi love a good sauna! I would have around 3 ft of inoculated woodchips/cardboard layered with hey:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeNeoc7fQM4&list=PLihFHKqj6JerqOGegzgVgGHu3z7VBNlJF

Comment: i can't seem to fing their follow up video on the compost pile

Comment: Guys, what is up with this fungus trend, fad, process?  I do not understand this at all.  How is this beneficial to anyone, anything?  Fungus is here.  Provide enough moisture...and there will plenty of fungus. What is it you think fungus does, adds to and promotes in the garden?  Why is more better?